# How to use Dynamic values in Vagrantfile e.g. Shell variables

Tags: bash, shell, vagrantfile

I have a simple Vagrantfile which has some static values e.g. server name, hostname and IP address. Here is my Vagrantfile.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

ENV['VAGRANT_NO_PARALLEL'] = 'yes'

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "bootstrap.sh"

  # Kubernetes Master Server
  config.vm.define "kmaster" do |kmaster|
    kmaster.vm.box = "centos/7"
    kmaster.vm.hostname = "kmaster.example.com"
    kmaster.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.42.42.100"
    kmaster.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.name = "kmaster"
      v.memory = 2048
      v.cpus = 2
    end
    kmaster.vm.provision "shell", path: "bootstrap_kmaster.sh"
  end

  NodeCount = 2

  # Kubernetes Worker Nodes
  (1..NodeCount).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "kworker#{i}" do |workernode|
      workernode.vm.box = "centos/7"
      workernode.vm.hostname = "kworker#{i}.example.com"
      workernode.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.42.42.10#{i}"
      workernode.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.name = "kworker#{i}"
        v.memory = 1024
        v.cpus = 1
      end
      workernode.vm.provision "shell", path: "bootstrap_kworker.sh"
    end
  end

end
```

The following shell script generates IP addresses and hosts names etc and saves it to sample.txt file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#set -e
File=sample.txt
i=0
for ip in 172.42.42.{100..120}
do
        echo 172.42.42.{1..10} | grep -q "\<$ip\>" && continue
    ((i++))
    rand=`cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 5 | head -n 1`
    if [[ $i -le 1 ]]; then

         kmaster="${ip} kmaster${rand}.example.com kmaster${rand}"

         if grep -q $kmaster "$File";
        then
            echo " entery already exist in host file.. skipping entry"
            echo -e "\e[01;31mMaster Node is already exist in /etc/hosts file, aborting script execution\e[0m"
            exit $ERRCODE
        else
            echo $kmaster >> sample.txt
            echo $kmaster >> master.txt
        fi
    else
        kworker="${ip} kworker$((i))${rand}.example.com kworker$((i))${rand}"
        if grep -q $kworker "$File";
        then
            echo " Entery already exist in host file ... skipping entry"
            echo -e "\e[01;31mWorker Node is already exist in /etc/hosts file, aborting script execution\e[0m"
            exit $ERRCODE

        else
            echo $kworker >> sample.txt
            echo $kworker >> kworker.txt
        fi
       fi          
done
```

the output of the above shell script

```
172.42.42.100 kmasterHees5.example.com kmasterHees5
172.42.42.101 kworker2CCGET.example.com kworker2CCGET
172.42.42.102 kworker3iyDPN.example.com kworker3iyDPN
172.42.42.103 kworker4vTiDG.example.com kworker4vTiDG
172.42.42.104 kworker5eaINq.example.com kworker5eaINq
172.42.42.105 kworker6cLqPv.example.com kworker6cLqPv
172.42.42.106 kworker7o4gEQ.example.com kworker7o4gEQ
172.42.42.107 kworker8XSHBS.example.com kworker8XSHBS
172.42.42.108 kworker9SMNqc.example.com kworker9SMNqc
172.42.42.109 kworker10sV8LR.example.com kworker10sV8LR
172.42.42.110 kworker11eG3kt.example.com kworker11eG3kt
172.42.42.111 kworker128ZvkB.example.com kworker128ZvkB
172.42.42.112 kworker13su92U.example.com kworker13su92U
172.42.42.113 kworker14sL5lh.example.com kworker14sL5lh
172.42.42.114 kworker158de2K.example.com kworker158de2K
172.42.42.115 kworker16chq6W.example.com kworker16chq6W
172.42.42.116 kworker17OIpHA.example.com kworker17OIpHA
172.42.42.117 kworker18Q4UCF.example.com kworker18Q4UCF
172.42.42.118 kworker19PAahY.example.com kworker19PAahY
172.42.42.119 kworker20GMHHd.example.com kworker20GMHHd
172.42.42.120 kworker2160RK6.example.com kworker2160RK6
```

The next step is to loop through the sample.txt file and save values into variables.

```
for i in ` sed s'/=/ /g' sample.txt | awk '{print $1}' `
   do  
   declare ip_addr="$i"
   #echo $ip_addr
   done


for i in ` sed s'/=/ /g' sample.txt | awk '{print $2}' `
   do  
   declare host="$i"
   #echo $link
   done


for i in ` sed s'/=/ /g' sample.txt | awk '{print $3}' `
   do  
   declare name="$i"
   #echo $name
   done
```

How can I put shell variables e.g. $ip_add or $host or name $name from the above script into Vagrant file?

Please suggest any working solution.

Thanks

Comment: I'd strongly suggest `export`ing your shell variables to make them *environment* variables, after which you can use Ruby's usual mechanisms to access them.

Comment: BTW, we generally ask that code in a question be a [mcve] -- the *shortest possible code* someone else can run without changes to reproduce your problem or test proposed solutions.

Comment: I'd also generally suggest running the whole shell script through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it flags. There are a lot of portability and efficiency issues -- putting `>>whatever`  on your individual commands re-opens the file `whatever` before each command, flushing and closing it after; and `echo $foo` without quoting it as `echo "$foo"` [has various bugs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: Moreover, even the POSIX spec for `echo` itself suggests using `printf` instead in cases where you might otherwise use `-n` or backslash-escape sequences; see the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `export host` (or `declare -x host`) on the shell side, then you can refer to `ENV["host"]` inside Ruby code started from that shell.

---

BTW, it would be much more reasonable to write the shell side of the code more akin to the following:

```
export ip_addr host name # mark all three variables for export to the environment
while IFS='= ' read -r ip_addr host name <&3; do  # read a line from FD 3
  vagrant up 3<&-                                 # and run your vagrant command
done 3<sample.txt                                 # with sample.txt open on FD 3
```